# iOS BLE Supported Connection Types

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on a BLE device that part of its requirements is that it'll only use connect mode between the iPhone and the peripheral (no pairing nor bonding).

According to Apple documentation [Bluetooth Accessory
Design Guidelines for
Apple Products](https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf)
section 3.7 Apple is using Random device address. As much as I know, when using Random device address one need to pair (in order to get the IRK).

Is there a way to have a BLE device who works with iOS and only does connect with no pairing or bonding?

Comment: core Bluetooth will provide an identifier. This identifier isn't the MAC but it is consistent and can be stored in order to reconnect to the peripheral.

Comment: thank you @Paulw11 for the prompt response. Can you please elaborate? you mean the UUID? So I can use iPhone without pairing or bonding?

Comment: That's right. You only need to bond if you use encrypted attributes

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11, I'll try it out.